# how to move scrollbars simultaneously in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have two view  whose perspectives are xy and xz.  These views have their own scrollbars and x side of these views are equal. When i move scroll bar of x sides , i want x scrollbars to move simultaneously.

Class of views is `QGraphicsView` and scrollbars of these views are their own scrollbar.
How can i make it? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could simply do the following (if you use QScrollBar as your scrollbar)

```
connect(firstScrollbar, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), secondScrollbar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(secondScrollbar, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), firstScrollbar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

Hope this answers your question and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this trying to synchronize two PlainTextEdits. For that I also had to respond to the cursorPositionChanged signal to synchronize the scrolling when the keyboard is used (arrow keys, Page Up/Down) like so:

```
firstScrollbar.connect(SIGNAL('cursorPositionChanged()')) do
  secondScrollbar.setValue(firstScrollBar.value)
end
```

Code example is in Ruby via [qtbindings](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/)